# Setting up tsconfig with spec/test folder

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

Say I put my code under `src` and tests under `spec`:

```
+ spec
+ --- classA.spec.ts
+ src
+ --- classA.ts
+ --- classB.ts
+ --- index.ts
+ tsconfig.json
```

I want to only transpile `src` to the `dist` folder. Since `index.ts` is the entry point of my package, my `tsconfig.json` look like this:

```
{
  "compileOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs"
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "files": {
    "src/index.ts",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  }
}
```

However, this `tsconfig.json` does not include the test files so I could not resolve dependencies in them.

On the other hand, if I include the test files into `tsconfig.json` then they are also transpiled to `dist` folder.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Similar question and working (quite elegant) answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61153019/3082178.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I ended up defining multiple config files and use `extends` to simplify them.

Say I have two files: `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.build.json`

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  ...
  "exclude": [...]
}

// tsconfig.build.json
{
  ...
  "files": [ "typings/index.d.ts", "src/index.ts" ]
}
```

This way, I can have fine control on what to build (using `tsc -p tsconfig.build.json`) and what the `ts language service` (IDE) handles.

UPDATE: now as my projects grow, I ended up having more config files. I use the "extend" feature that is now available in TypeScript:

```
// tsconfig.base.json
{
  // your common settings. Mostly "compilerOptions".
  // Do not include "files" and "include" here,
  // let individual config handles that.
  // You can use "exclude" here, but with "include",
  // It's pretty much not necessary.
}

// tsconfig.json
{
  // This is used by `ts language service` and testing.
  // Includes source and test files.
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "atom": { ... },
  "compilerOptions": {
    // I set outDir to place all test build in one place,
    // and avoid accidentally running `tsc` littering test build to my `src` folder.
    "outDir": "out/spec"  
  }
  "include": [ ... ]
}

// tsconfig.commonjs.json or tsconfig.systemjs.json or tsconfig.global.json etc
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    // for some build this does not apply
    "declaration": true/false,
    "outDir": "dist/<cjs, sys, global, etc>",
    "sourceRoot": "..."
  },
  // Only point to typings and the start of your source, e.g. `src/index.ts`
  "files": [ ... ],
  "include": [ ... ]
 }
```

Comment: It might now be worth using the Typescript 3 [Project Refernces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) feature, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51631786/how-to-use-project-references-in-typescript-3-0

Comment: That is more for monorepo project referencing. I use it in my monorepos such as https://github.com/unional/standard-log

Answer (score 62):

Here is a detailed solution to manage sources and tests:

- compilation includes sources and tests folders/files
- build includes only sources
- IDE (VSCode, ...)

### Config

The solution is based on 2 `tsconfig.json` files as mentioned in other answers.

**The main `./tsconfig.json`** (used for compilation and IDE):

```
{
  "compileOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs"
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": [
    "spec/**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "files": [
    "src/index.ts"
  ]
}
```

**The second `./tsconfig-build.json`** (used for build):

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": [
    "spec/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

*Note: we exclude test files that have been included previously*

### Build

Build command: `tsc -p tsconfig-build.json`

Or `npm run build` if script is added in `package.json`:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig-build.json",
}
```

Answer (score 18):

This is somewhat dependent on whatever testing framework you're using but I like to use [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) to compile my test files. Using mocha, your `npm test` script might look like:

```
"mocha": "mocha test/ --compilers ts:ts-node/register --recursive"
```

In your tsconfig.json, make sure to remove the `rootDir` option.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "lib"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "lib",
        "typings/**"
    ]
}
```

When you try to run typescript with `rootDir` set to `src` or whatever the base folder for your application code is, it'll disallow any compilation in a directory that sits outside, such a `tests`. Using `ts-node`, you can easily keep everything separate without having to have separate TypeScript configuration files.

Comment: Not separating into multiple config files has the drawback of distributing extra (test) files in the package. Also, your two `include` are redundant. You only need `src/**/*.ts`

Answer (score 2):

I think you should not use 'files' option in your config. Instead you can exclude unwanted files and have it like this:

```
{ 
    "compilerOptions": { 
        "module": "commonjs", 
        "outDir": "dist"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist",
        "typings/browser.d.ts",
        "typings/browser/**"
    ]
}
```

This will preserve your original structure in the 'dist' folder without mixing tests and app js files:

```
--dist
----spec
-------....
----src
-------....
```

Comment: But he doesn't want the test files to end up in the `dist` folder *at all*. Which is logical, they are not for publication. Having them in a subdir there does not really help. I too want my project files and only those end up in `lib/`, and the files under `test/` remain where they are. If the .js version of the test files is moved somewhere else I would have *two* new problems: a) Exclude them from publication, b) have test runners find them, sure solvable, but it piles hack on top of hack. Unnecessary if tsc could just store the test files in the test directory.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add an include directory of the source files you want compiled and included in your build. Next, specify your exclude directory in tsconfig.json. For your use case it isn't necessary to have multiple tsconfig files.

```
{
  "include": [ "src/**/*" ],
  "exclude": [ "./spec" ]
}
```

Comment: Will this setup allow intellisense and refactoring in VSCode?

Comment: You will need to keep this tsconfig file updated manually when you do large refactors (changing the source folder or where your specs are). There might be a VSCode plugin to detect these changes, but I doubt it.

Comment: @AKd nope, for VSCode to auto-import/code-complete your files, it must be included in the respective `tsconfig`

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because my jest version was 26 and my ts-jest version was 27 so they were out of sync.

```sh
yarn jest --version
```

```sh
yarn add ts-jest@26
```

my jest.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    preset: "ts-jest",
    moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx"],
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
    },
    globals: {
        "ts-jest": {
            diagnostics: false,
        },
    },
    testMatch: ["**/*.(test|spec).(ts|tsx|js|jsx)"],
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/"],
    coverageReporters: ["json", "lcov", "text", "text-summary"],
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(firebase/.*|react/.*)/)",
    ],
    testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen",
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$":
            "<rootDir>/__mocks__/mocks.js",
        "\\.(css|less|scss)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/mocks.js",
        "^src/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
    },
};
```