# TypeScript: How to import from parent folder when compilation adds depth to project structure

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

My project structure is as follows

```
dist
  |- src
  |   |- s.js
  |- test
      |- t.js
node_modules
results
  |- r.json
src
  |- s.ts
test
  |- t.ts
tsconfig.json
typings.d.ts
```

**s.ts** imports **r.json** as follows:

`import * as results from '../results/r.json';`

Obviously, this doesn't work after compilation as **results** is now two folders up...

What is the proper approach to fix this? Below is my **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist/",
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "./typings.d.ts"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "results/r.json",
    "test/**/*.ts",
    "./typings.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to avoid this altogether. Try to make the depth level matches.

e.g.:

```
root
  dist-es5
    index.ts
    index.spec.ts
  src
    index.ts
    index.spec.ts
```

As for keeping the test/spec code from distributed, you can have multiple `tsconfig.json`
e.g. you can take a look at: [Setting up tsconfig with spec/test folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470511/setting-up-tsconfig-with-spec-test-folder/37555279#37555279)

Comment: I followed your advice. Until there's a better solution, I put my src and test folders under an **app** folder. This way in the source code the results folder is also 2 levels up. Thanks!