# How to use project references in TypeScript 3.0?

Tags: typescript

There is a new feature in TypeScript 3.0 called [Project References](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html). It suggests better interaction of `*.ts` modules between themselves.

Can anyone help me understand exactly, what problems does it solve, how does it do that, and how would I benefit from it? I have a project with a similar structure, so it might (or might not) be very helpful for it.

The project structure is roughly:

```yaml
project/
    lib/
        index.ts # defines the original code
    test/
        index.spec.ts # requires lib/index.ts
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
```

Answer (score 160, accepted):

## TL;DR:

The feature allows defining parts of the project as separate TypeScript modules. Among other things, this allows configuring those modules differently, building them separately, etc.

---

## Before

Initially, the [project structure](https://github.com/parzh/re-scaled/tree/50afae2e1ad7c2dd1799a4b92e77efd7d58aa1f9), when simplified, is similar to this:

```yaml
/
    src/
        entity.ts # exports an entity
    test/
        entity.spec.ts # imports an entity
    tsconfig.json
```

<sub>An entity is [defined in `src/entity.ts` module](https://github.com/parzh/re-scaled/blob/50afae2e1ad7c2dd1799a4b92e77efd7d58aa1f9/src/index.ts#L3), and then [used in `test/entity.spec.ts` file](https://github.com/parzh/re-scaled/blob/50afae2e1ad7c2dd1799a4b92e77efd7d58aa1f9/test/unit/combined.spec.ts#L5).</sub>

Notice that there is only one `tsconfig.json` file here, sitting in the root folder. This basically says that this folder contains one big solid TypeScript project. This project includes a couple of files, organized in folders; some of those files are used for testing other ones.

This structure however imposes a problem: the process of compiling the project (namely, `tsc`) also compiles the test files, thus creating `dist/test/entity.spec.{js|d.ts}` files in the output. This should not happen, therefore the `tsconfig.json` file is slightly altered to include only those files/folders that are intended for outside usage:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // compiler options
    },
    "include": [
        "./src"
    ]
}
```

This kind of solves the problem, however now all files in `/test` are completely unrelated to the files in `/src`. Specifically, `/test` has its own compiler options; so, for example setting `strictNullCheck` to `true` in `tsconfig.json` will lead to inconsistent errors, because it is `false` (by default) for the files in `/test`.

This is obviously very wrong.

---

## After

After [utilizing the feature](https://github.com/parzh/re-scaled/commit/ca47c1f6195b211ed5d61d2821864c8cecd86bad), the project structure has changed to this:

```yaml
/
    src/
        entity.ts # exports an entity
        tsconfig.json
    test/
        entity.spec.ts # imports an entity
        tsconfig.json
    tsconfig-base.json
```

Let's go through the changes:

1. Renaming `/tsconfig.json` to `/tsconfig-base.json` is a pretty major thing by itself: the root folder is not a TypeScript project anymore, since `tsc` requires the `tsconfig.json` file to be present.
2. On the other hand, adding `src/tsconfig.json` and `test/tsconfig.json` files turns both `src` and `test` into two separate TypeScript projects, independent from each other.

The contents of `/{src|test}/tsconfig.json` files are similar since no changes in the configuration were expected, i.e., the "strictness", the output folder, as well as other such parameters, should be preserved. In order to make them similar without copy-pasting anything, [all the configurations are put in an arbitrary file](https://github.com/parzh/re-scaled/blob/ca47c1f6195b211ed5d61d2821864c8cecd86bad/tsconfig.json), accessible from both places; in this case, the `tsconfig-base.json` in the root folder was selected for that:

```json
// the contents of /tsconfig-base.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // compiler options, common to both projects
    }
}
```

[This file is being "inherited" then](https://github.com/parzh/re-scaled/blob/ca47c1f6195b211ed5d61d2821864c8cecd86bad/src/tsconfig.json#L2) by `/{src|test}/tsconfig.json` files, with addition of any other options if needed:

```json
// the contents of /{src|test}/tsconfig.json
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig-base.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        // additional compiler options, specific to a project
    }
}
```

> Notice how this pattern is similar to defining an `abstract class` with incomplete implementation, and then extending it by two separate "concrete" classes.

Now, `/src` and `/test` folders basically hold two separate TypeScript projects with similar configurations. The last thing to do is to specify the relation between the two.  Since `test` depends on `src`, the `test` has to somehow "know" about `src`. This is done in two pretty obvious steps:

- [allow `src` to be "referenced"](https://github.com/parzh/re-scaled/blob/ca47c1f6195b211ed5d61d2821864c8cecd86bad/src/tsconfig.json#L4) from the outside by declaring it as "composite":

  ```json
  // in /src/tsconfig.json
  {
      "extends": "../tsconfig-base.json",
      "compilerOptions": {
          // compiler options
          "composite": true
      }
  }
  ```
- [reference `src` from `test`](https://github.com/parzh/re-scaled/blob/ca47c1f6195b211ed5d61d2821864c8cecd86bad/test/tsconfig.json#L4):

  ```json
  // in /test/tsconfig.json
  {
      "extends": "../tsconfig-base.json",
      "references": [
          { "path": "../src" }
      ]
  }
  ```

The `"include"` array in `/tsconfig-base.json` [is not needed now](https://github.com/parzh/re-scaled/blob/ca47c1f6195b211ed5d61d2821864c8cecd86bad/tsconfig.json), since the code exclusion is done by "drawing new borders".

> *UPDATE: the following section seems to be outdated since [TypeScript 3.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#build-free-editing-with-project-references)*

Now, the `test` project requires `*.d.ts` files for the `src` project to be present. This means that before running tests, the `src` should already be built, separately. This is done by [using the new mode of `tsc`](https://github.com/parzh/re-scaled/blob/ca47c1f6195b211ed5d61d2821864c8cecd86bad/package.json#L11), triggered by the `--build` option:

```
tsc --build src
```

This command builds the `src` project and puts the output in the specified output folder (in this case, `/dist`), without neither breaking `test` nor losing any compile errors.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this Dmitry, I appreciate your insight.

Comment: I wish the official docs were so clear as this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show actual code in the test directory? Is `path` significant here as in we `import { myFunction } from "path"`. Feel like this answer is missing a crucial piece.

Comment: @brainkim There is a couple of links to the project, where it is used. I've edited the answer to add a couple more, and make them more obvious. Also, the source of the project is open, feel free to further investigate

Comment: Still no example of importing. A link to gitlab is not sufficient.

Comment: @ChrisFremgen I'm not completely sure, what exactly is missing. Is it the usage of `export` and `import` statements? If so, it is **not changed**; opting-in to Project References doesn't change that syntax. I thought that's obvious and just made a link, instead of copying the code. If you still feel like the code should be directly present in the answer, please let me know

Comment: I had to add `"paths": { "@my/theme": ["../theme/source/"] }` as well as `"references": [{ "path": "../theme/" }]` to get it to work. Builds that don’t change anything run in less than a second now. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: So...project references have nothing to do with module resolution, is that right? This is only to cut down on compilation time by telling the compiler "I depend on project A, and if that is up to date, we can go faster" ?

Comment: What if the reference project has its own dependencies specified in a package.json file? I am running into bit of a problem and I have posted a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67070255/typescript-project-references-handle-third-party-dependencies-of-referenced-pro

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine What's actually missing is the actual usage. :-) As others have mentioned, "paths" can be used to comfortably refer to the sibling project. The problems is not with building but with running. Package.json's equivalent to "paths", "import" doesn't allow reference to outside the package, that is, you can't reference the sibling project when running. It compiles but it doesn't run.

Answer (score 3):

It's for TypeScript libraries you develop, that are used by other TypeScript application. So for example, if you make some util library like `lodash` but are actively developing it along side your dependent application, the `references` in ``tsconfig.json``` lets you reference the source code, and have your dependent  application be rebuilt automatically when the util source changes (i.e.: `tsc` detects source code changes in the util ts lib)

In my case specifically, I use the `references` in conjunction with `npm link` and git `submodules` and it's working out a lot better than in the `ts 2.x` days.

Comment: I've added a rough representation of the project structure. If I understood your answer correctly, it would make sense to create `project/test/tsconfig.json` file and specify `project/lib/index.ts` in its `references`, right? This looks a bit weird, so correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @DmitryParzhitsky you can look at my open source typescript project for an example.   search npm for "xlib" and "phantomjscloud".  the first is the library, the 2nd uses it.   Locally I have phantomjscloud reference xlib via ```npm link xlib```