# Typescript: Make tsconfig emit one folder but not the other folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, webpack

I'm converting an existing project from js to typescript. I want to be able to set `noEmit = true` on one folder but have the other folder have `noEmit = false`.

The reason is that I have my client(angular) code set up through webpack and do not need typescript to generate the javascript for me. While the server (Node/express) still needs to be generated into javascript.

I've tried a few different combinations but haven't seem to find the right way to do it.

My only solution that I've been able to get to work is having two `tsconfig.json` and running a command like `tsc -p src\server\tsconfig && tsc -p src\client\tsconfig`

I realize that this is not a good solution, but I have not gotten a single tsconfig to work nor having a base tsconfig.

Here is the folder structure..

```
|-Src
|--/client
|--/server
```

Is there a way to achieve this using a single tsc command? Or is there a better way I should be formatting the project? Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's another solution besides having multiple tsconfig.json files like you're already doing, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37555279/6157047) and [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin/issues/605#issuecomment-299581036).

You can make this a little more streamlined by having a `tsconfig.json` for compilation and a separate `tsconfig-build.json` that you use in your package.json for building, i.e.:

```
// package.json
{
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc -p tsconfig-build.json"
    },
    // ...
}
```

With this setup (assuming the default tsconfig.json [is in your root](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#using-tsconfigjson)), running `tsc` from the command line will use the default tsconfig.json, but running `npm run build` will use tsconfig-build.json. You can also have [one tsconfig extend from another](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#configuration-inheritance-with-extends), so if you have a lot of options in common, you could add a `tsconfig-base.json` that both configs extend from.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve what you want with the exclude property in your tsconfig.json file.

Check the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)
for the exclude property

Comment: That will then exclude the client folder from the typescript compiler checking. I still want that functionality , just not have it emit

Comment: I see i think you are stuck with your solution since you can't specify the noEmit property per files/directories. 
I suppose you are using ts-loader, if so then you should have the compiler checking via webpack and remove your second command