# Is It possible to verify a TypeScript file without compiling it?

Tags: typescript, configuration-files

I have the `src` and `test` folders in my project. Since I don't want to compile my test files, I have ignored them in my `tsconfig.json` file with the `exclude` property, but I noticed that this also made TypeScript stopping verifying if my files are correct during the coding, so then I just see my errors when I run the tests. Is it possible to make TypeScript verify my code without compiling it? If yes, how? And if no, what do you suggest to solve my problem?

If It's any useful, here's my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "test"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53856082/typescript-make-tsconfig-emit-one-folder-but-not-the-other-folder

Comment: Why don’t you want to compile?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, thank you!
@Ezra Well, I use Jest for tests and It doesn't need `.js` files to run, since It understands TypeScript. Another reason is because, in my point of view, the `build` folder (where my compiled files are saved) should be a copy of the `src` but with the compiled files, and the `test` folder is out the `src` folder. But I don't now if this idea is correct (or if It is a good practice).