# ESLint with TypeScript parser/plugin: how to include .spec.ts, that is excluded from tsconfig.json?

Tags: typescript, eslint, tsconfig, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

I'm using the awesome [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) together with ESLint.

**Problem description**: the TypeScript ESLint parser complains about `src/module.spec.ts` not being part of the project, and this is correct. I'm excluding all `spec.ts` files from TypeScript `tsconfig.json` file because they don't need to be transpiled.

How to make `src/module.spec.ts` **not transplied but still checked** against ESLint?

> my-project\src\module.spec.ts
>   0:0  error  Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.
>   The file does not match your project config: src\module.spec.ts.
>   The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided

My `.eslint.json` (stripped down):

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "env": {
    "node": true
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "project": "tsconfig.json"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ]
}
```

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "removeComments": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "./dist",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but basically the same solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470511/setting-up-tsconfig-with-spec-test-folder

Answer (score 5):

In the project folder containing `tsconfig.json`, create another JSON file with the following contents:

```
{
  "exclude": [
    "./dist"
  ],
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json"
}
```

The exact file name is irrelevant here. Note that this is a perfectly valid TypeScript configuration file where all settings are inherited from `./tsconfig.json`, execept for `extends`, where the pattern `"**/*.spec.ts"` has been removed.

A tool that reads its settings from this new JSON file (as opposed to the default `tsconfig.json`) will *not* ignore `src/module.spec.ts`.

Then in your `.eslint.json` under `parserOptions` set the name of the new JSON file as `project`, e.g. if the file is called `test.tsconfig.json`:

```
"project": "test.tsconfig.json"
```

Then run ESLint and see what else it's complaining about.

This is basically what I'm doing in one of my projects having encountered a similar problem. There must be probably a few other ways to achieve the same effect.

Comment: But test.tsconfig.json will then ovverride the project tsconfig.json right? Or we can have both?

Comment: Exactly. TypeScript uses `tsconfig.json` per default, while typescript-eslint uses whatever file is set as `project` is the ESLint config.

Comment: Oh, I see. Clever. By the way, why repeating exclude key? Isn’t better to name it like tsconfig.eslint.conf instead? Is there any naming convention?

Comment: See my updated answer. I couldn't find anything about naming conventions, VSCode and other IDEs only recognize `tsconfig.json` as a TS config file. Anyway the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) provides two examples of alternative names: `configs/base.json` and `tsconfig.nostrictnull.json` (both unconventional, though).

Comment: So in a monorepo, I have to create 2 tsconfigs per project just so I can have my tests linted?